# Authlib token expiration

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, authlib

I'm using Authlib to create the OAuth flow in my application. The expiration time doesn't work, e.g, if I get the code of the [example](https://github.com/authlib/example-oauth2-server/blob/master/website/oauth2.py#L61) and add the expiration [time](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/oauth2.html#server) set to 1800:

```
OAUTH2_TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN = {
    'authorization_code': 1800,
    'implicit': 1800,
    'password': 1800,
    'client_credentials': 1800
}
```

I still receiving the token with the expiration time of 864000 seconds. How to solve this ? I have try to set the expiration of the Flask session but it still not working

Comment: What is your Authlib version?

Comment: My version is 0.9

Comment: I added a test for it https://github.com/lepture/authlib/commit/3ea921e7b5bf763a801b36348cde5732b29ef378

Answer (score 0):

Setting this value worked for the Django authorization server.

```
AUTHLIB_OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    'token_expires_in': {
        'authorization_code': 1800 
    }
}
```

Looking at the flask authorization server, it looks like it should be similar. The `create_bearer_token_generator` function in `authlib/integrations/flask_oauth2/authorization_server.py` sets the `expires_in` value by grabbing it from your flask config.

I would try setting a breakpoint there to see if your config is set up right.